# fb native app not showing in canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook

Sorry that I really am coming into this question with very little knowledge.

I am trying to make a simple app at this point.

I started the developer account, and then I made a html document on my pc and put it on my webserver.

I then included the js sdk and login which it says you must.

The html document now looks like this

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Westgate Mall Loyalty Program</title>



    </head>

    <body>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '1691221377775124',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.4'
      });

      // ADD ADDITIONAL FACEBOOK CODE 
      function onLogin(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
      var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
      welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!';
    });
  }
}

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // Check login status on load, and if the user is
  // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    onLogin(response);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
    FB.login(function(response) {
      onLogin(response);
    }, {scope: 'user_friends, email'});
  }
});
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <script>
document.write(5 + 6);
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now when i click the button open your app it opens a page with nothing in it but broken page symbol in the middle of a white page.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does your server support https? And does it support POST requests?

Comment: What button are we talking about? I don't see you embedded any plugins in the page.